# PowerBI filter within 3 date ranges

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have a table with account number and 3 dates (balloon, maturity, and rate change). I want to filter these collectively where if ANY one field has a date within the next 36 months from a filtered Process Date that whole row gets returned. Using relative dates only returns rows fitting all 3 within the next 36 months.

I have come close with

```
filtcol = 

if(not(isblank(ds[BalloonDate])),(datediff(ds[AsOfDate], ds[BalloonDate], month) <=36), blank())
||
if(not(isblank(ds[MaturityDate])),(datediff(ds[AsOfDate], ds[MaturityDate], month) <=36), blank())
||
if(not(isblank(ds[ChangeDate])),(datediff(ds[AsOfDate], ds[ChangeDate], month) <=36), blank())
```

This correctly labels those rows with dates within 36 months as TRUE and those beyond as FALSE, but it also labels dates with past values as TRUE, what gives?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATEDIFF(D1, D2, X)` will return a negative number if D2 is before D1. You will need to check if between 0 and 36.

An example using `VAR` for local variables, and a `SWITCH` that may help with readability.

```
filtcol = 
  var diffBallon = DATEDIFF(ds[AsOfDate], ds[BalloonDate], MONTH)
  var diffMaturity = DATEDIFF(ds[AsOfDate], ds[MaturityDate], MONTH)
  var diffChange = DATEDIFF(ds[AsOfDate], ds[ChangeDate], MONTH)

  return SWITCH( TRUE(),
    0 <= diffBallon && diffBallon <= 36, TRUE(),
    0 <= diffMaturity && diffMaturity <= 36, TRUE(),
    0 <= diffChange && diffChange <= 36, TRUE(),
    FALSE()
  )
```